Power Automate SharePoint Get File Content
I created a flow to concatenate some txt files from a Sharepoint folder, and most of this seems to be working quite well, except the "Get file content" from Sharepoint.

The workflow uses "Get files (properties only)" to extract a list of files from the folder, but at the end I need the inner contents of the source file and I don´t seem to be able to make it correctly reference the approved files within the loop "For each" condition.

For the File identifier, I have tried to use the file ID, file name, path+file name... nothing worked.
I´m sure it is quite easy and obvious, but I just don´t seem to be able to correctly reference it.

I just figured out that "Get file content" needs a path in URI enconding, such as
/Shared%20Documents/file.txt

And that by replacing this module for "Get file content using path" has solved the issue, and I was able to use the regular path without URI enconding:
/Shared Documents/file.txt


You can use uriComponent(<Your Path>) function to convert your path into uri encoded path.

Your sharing is great! It works for me.
